# Indenting C code, Unix

Tags: c, linux, unix, indentation

I searched documentation for indent, but I gave up eventually, I want to indent code like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    some code;
}
```

I know indent -kr gives you braces like this, but -kr style also includes

```
int
main(int argc, char **argv){
    some code;
}
```

and this int in line before main gives me creeps.

Can anyone please tell me option for this?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce that, but I do see a `-npsl` option which should switch that back off.

Comment: You're not using an IDE/editor with style options?

Comment: Nope, just plain text editor.

Comment: @John, your command doesn't give braces like I want (see above).

Comment: @АлександарМакрагић It seems pretty clear that you and I have somewhat different versions of indent.

Comment: Have you tried `man indent`? That gives me complete documentation both on OS X and Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particular options that you are interested in are

> **`-npsl`**
> **`--dont-break-procedure-type`**
> Put the type of a procedure on the same line as its name.
>
> **`-brf`**
> **`--braces-on-func-def-line`**
> Put braces on function definition line.

As suggested, the [GNU indent manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/manual/indent.html) describes the various options.

Here is a quick script to illustrate the effect of those options on the basic predefined styles:

```
#!/bin/sh
for opt in gnu linux orig kr
do
    echo "** $opt"
    indent -st -$opt -npsl -brf hello.c
done
```

and the input file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) { int n; for (n = 0; n < argc; ++n) printf("arg%d=%s\n", n, argv[n]); return 0; }
```

and corresponding output:

```
** gnu
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n;
    for (n = 0; n < argc; ++n)
        printf("arg%d=%s\n", n, argv[n]);
    return 0;
}
** linux
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n;
    for (n = 0; n < argc; ++n)
        printf("arg%d=%s\n", n, argv[n]);
    return 0;
}
** orig
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int             n;
    for (n = 0; n < argc; ++n)
        printf("arg%d=%s\n", n, argv[n]);
    return 0;
}
** kr
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n;
    for (n = 0; n < argc; ++n)
        printf("arg%d=%s\n", n, argv[n]);
    return 0;
}
```

I do not see an option to suppress the space before the `{` character.

Comment: That answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely looking for the `-npsl` option. The `-psl` (`--procnames-start-lines`) option causes the type of a procedure being defined to be placed on the line before the name of the  procedure. Thus if you specify that option, all function declarations will be changed from:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    some code;
}
```

to

```
int
main(int argc, char **argv){
    some code;
}
```

You can check whether you are including `-psl` in the common type `-kr` and remove it, or if not included, you can specify `-npsl` (`--dont-break-procedure-type`) and the type will not be placed on a separate line.

There are trade-off with all options. I like braces on the same line as `int main() {`, but for function definitions I like braces on the next line. e.g.:

```
type function
{
    ...
}
```

So if you have mutually exclusive preferences such as that, you simply choose the one you want a majority of the code to incorporate and tweak the rest. You might give the following invocation a try:

```
indent -i 4 -lp -ts 8 -lp -lps -br -brs -blf -ce -cdw -pcs -bs -nbc -npsl -saf -sai -saw -nut
```

It is somewhat of a balanced indent scheme.